# Selecting an entity in a 2 table (database)

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my `mysql_query`

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT calendar.datefield AS dateRow, po.po_no,cus_name,net FROM payments
                   RIGHT JOIN po ON payments.po_id=po.po_id
                   RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(po.po_date) = calendar.datefield)
                   WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN '$sDateFrom' AND '$sDateTo'
                  ") or die(mysql_error());// AND payments.pay_status='Paid'
?>
```

and I wanted to select another entity from another table which is

```
prod_desc FROM del_details
```

How can i do it using the same format query?

common key is the po_id

Comment: How is `del_details` related to your other tables?

Comment: do you have any common keys from any of these tables?  If so, you can do it the same way

Comment: del_details is a table prod_desc is an entity from table del_details yeah and the common key is the po_id

Answer (score 0):

Add LEFT / RIGHT join depending on your need..

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT calendar.datefield AS dateRow, po.po_no,cus_name,net, del_details.prod_desc 
                   FROM payments
                   RIGHT JOIN po ON payments.po_id=po.po_id
                   RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(po.po_date) = calendar.datefield)
                   JOIN del_details ON payments.po_id=po.po_id
                   WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN '$sDateFrom' AND '$sDateTo'
                  ") or die(mysql_error());// AND payments.pay_status='Paid'
```

Comment: the column or entity that I need to select is prod_desc from del_details

Comment: yes, isn't this included in the query that I posted? "SELECT .... del_details.prod_desc". And notice the additional join query "JOIN del_details ON... "